# Javascript won't affect HTML element unless below it

Tags: javascript

If I'm trying to affect an HTML element with a script (getElementById) it only works if the script comes after the element. Isn't javascript code usually all at the top of the HTML doc? For example:

Why does this work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="helloMessage"> </p>
<script>
document.getElementById("helloMessage").innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but this does not

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.getElementById("helloMessage").innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
</script>
<p id="helloMessage"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because, in the second snippet, when JavaScript starts executing, the element is not present in the document (DOM). That's why your JS code cannot modify it. You cannot eat a pizza until you have it.

Comment: HTML is parsed line by line by the browser. If the script is before, the HTML element does not exist yet when the script is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the snippet is very specific snippet is placed before the element , then this line `document.getElementById("helloMessage")` will try to find an element from DOM whose id is `helloMessage` , since the element is not there it will not work

You can still put it before the html by putting this code inside `window.onload`

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("helloMessage").innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
    }
  </script>
  <p id="helloMessage"> </p>
</body>

</html>
```